# Problems with fgetcsv

Tags: fgetcsv

I have a csv excel file with 2 columns of values: latitudes and longitudes. I need to access each individual latitude and longitude value separately.

But I can't even read the csv file into an array properly. Since I'm using a mac, I started with:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);  
$handle = fopen("countlook.csv", "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",");
```

Which returns only the first line (column headings) "Latitude,Longitude" without any actual values.

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetcsv` reads the file line by line, so its important to put it in a loop to get all the data.

```
$headers = array();
$rows = array();
$c = 0;
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) {

        if ($c == 0) {
            $headers = $data;
            
        } else {
            $rows[] = $data;
        }

       $c ++;
    }
fclose($handle);
```

You should now have the headers in the `$headers` variable and all the data in the `$rows` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $data = array();
    while (($rawdata = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
         for ($i=0; $i < count($rawdata); $i++) {
              $data[$i][] = trim($rawdata[$i]);
         }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    var_dump($data)
}
```